# How do I load libries properly in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libraries

I am new to Android Studio but not new to programming.  I have done the tutorials for AndroidStudio and have produced my first app.  Now I want to add a graph.
I have downloaded `GraphView-4.2.2` from Maven.
I copied it into  app/libs
select `graphview-4.2.2-javadoc.jar`  right click and "add as library" then I get pop-up "Studio cannot determine what kind of files..." and provides a list of 7.  I have tried them all.
I think I should get a `com.jjoe64.graphview` folder and a `Meta-Inf` folder below graphview, but I only get the meta-inf.
I can't access any of the GraphView functions

I am using Android Studio 3.5 on a Win10 64bit PC

Comment: Add your gradle dependencies in your projects `build.gradle` file.

Comment: No need for any copy action. As already stated just integrate it into the dependencies of your gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include the entire library in your project, just add it in your dependencies. In the build.gradle file add the following: `implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'`

Have a look at the [official documentation on dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)
Extract:

> **Remote binary dependency**
>   implementation 'com.example.android:app-magic:12.3'
>
> This is actually shorthand for the following:
>
> implementation group: 'com.example.android', name: 'app-magic', version: '12.3'
>
> This declares a dependency on version 12.3 of the "app-magic" library, inside the "com.example.android" namespace group.
>
> Note: Remote dependencies like this require that you declare the appropriate remote repositories where Gradle should look for the library. **If the library does not already exist locally, Gradle pulls it from the remote site when the build requires it** (such as when you click Sync Project with Gradle Files or when you run a build).

**EDIT (after comments):**

I created a sample project myself and added the dependency above. I proceeded to create a standard layout and added the following code in my MainActivity and it works just fine:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(0, 1),
                new DataPoint(1, 5),
                new DataPoint(2, 3),
                new DataPoint(3, 2),
                new DataPoint(4, 6)
        });
        graph.addSeries(series);
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.content"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
}
```

Don't worry about the other dependencies, they come by default in my version of Android Studio and they shouldn't make a difference in that library.

Comment: Hi Nikos and @Zun,  Your comments were very helpful.  Solution was easier than I expected.  Still getting a "Cannot resolve symbol" error on   "graph.addSeries(series);" but I will persevere - I expect it is something obvious

Comment: @Rocket.Ian what is the symbol that's not resolved? is it the method addSeries or the objects?

Comment: This is the code snippet:
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph1);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>

            series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
}

It is the " graph.addSeries(series);" line

Comment: error looks like this :   graph.addSeries(series);  with the "addSeries in red.  and the message is "Cannot resolve symbol 'addSeries'"

Comment: @Rocket.Ian it seems that a lot of people are having similar issues with that library. A search on their repository returns many "cannot resolve" threads https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cannot++resolve+ including the same issue as yours, without any satisfactory answers https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/291

Comment: @Rocket.Ian check my edit and compare it with what you have. Try creating an empty activity and layout and copying in my code and see if it works.

Comment: Your code worked fine.  I have grafted in the rest of my code and I now have a little app that works, does the calcs I want and plots the graph.  It has been a struggle but I have made my first useful app.  Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure this out. Please consider accepting my answer and upvoting when you can.

Comment: I would accept your answer if I could see how to  !

Comment: @Rocket.Ian There's a checkmark that appears  (as long as you're logged in) at the top left side of every answer underneath the arrows for upvoting/downvoting. If you click that you accept the answer.